# Shiny - bookmarking tabs created via appendTab()

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm implementing a drill down in my app so that when user clicks on a data table new tab is opened showing details for the selected cell. I wanted to add auto bookmarking (url updates itself) to my app so I can send a link to a specific, newly generated tab but the tab is not restored correctly. I think the observer is not triggered during the restoration process. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- function(request) {
    dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(title = "Drilldown not restoring"),
        dashboardSidebar(disable = T),
        dashboardBody(
            tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
                        tabPanel("Cars overview",
                                 h1("Cars overview"),
                                 div("Click any cell"),
                                 br(),
                                 DT::dataTableOutput("mtcars")
                        )
            )
        )
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    # Generate data table
    output$mtcars <- DT::renderDataTable({mtcars})

    # Observe when row is selected and open new tab
    observeEvent(input$mtcars_rows_selected, {
        print("Trigger")
        appendTab(inputId = "tabs",
                  tabPanel(
                      "Car details",
                      "Car detail info"

                  )
        )
        # Focus on newly created tab
        updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabs", selected = "Car details")
    })

    # Enable bookmarking
    observe({
        reactiveValuesToList(input)
        session$doBookmark()
    })
    onBookmarked(function(url) {
        updateQueryString(url)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

Comment: Sorry, you're trying to give the car details with bookmark value?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to restore the "Car details" tab.

Comment: Hi @Mikolaj, were to able this issue. Even I am facing similar issue here